# Create window of a smaller depth than that of VisualInfo

Tags: x11, xlib

The depth value of visuals on my machine is 24. Is it possible to create X window of lower depth (for example 16) ?
If yes how ? Any pointer to sample code would be useful.

```
XSetWindowAttributes attrs;

attrs.colormap = XCreateColormap(dpy, XDefaultRootWindow(dpy), visual, AllocNone);
attrs.background_pixel = 0;
attrs.border_pixel = 0;

XCreateWindow(dpy, parent, 10, 10, 150, 100, 0, 16, InputOutput,
                visual, CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel, &attrs);
```

The above code gave me bad match error. The visual parameter is having 24 bit depth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all possible depths are available in all servers. Run `xdpyinfo | grep depths` to see what yours support, or call `XListDepths` from your application.

For example, on my home computer the X server supports depth of 16, but on my work computer it doesn't.

**EDIT** Window depth must exactly match visual depth, or BadMatch error occurs.

`XListDepths` may be used to query which visuals support given depth. If all visuals have depth of 24, then every window must have depth of 24. Not all listed depths may be realised as visuals on a given server.

Comment: I agree. I only see 24 bit depth support on my machine. So what exactly is the meaning of "maximal depth" ? From what I read, depth value in XCreateWindow() can be less than maximal depth.

Comment: "depth value in XCreateWindow() can be less than maximal depth" -- only if it is in the list of depths supported by the server. My work server supports depths of 24, 32, 8, 4, 1. I can create windows of depth 8 or 24, but not 16.

Comment: Theres a little confusion. The 'xdpyinfo' output says - 
screen #0:
depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32

But all the visuals have -
depth:    24 planes

Is it still possible to create a window with depth less than maximal depth even if I dont have a 'VISUAL' with 16 bit depth ?

Comment: Now you've got me doubting my own words. If you call XMatchVisualInfo with a depth of 16 will you get any matching visual?

Comment: Correct me if wrong. Since none of the visual has 16 bit depth, XMatchVisualInfo cannot return any matching visuals. I tried it on my machine to verify.

Comment: OK I have always thought one can create a window with less depth than the visual allows, but apparently this is completely wrong. See update. Do I feel stupid now.